# Android - fool-proof camera activity

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, android-camera

What I want to do is be able to take a picture with my app and return that picture to an activity...either to modify it or simply view it.  My possible problem or question is: How do I know this will work on all versions of Android phones? I know some phones run different versions/flavors of Android.  Some will also have a manufacturers software overlayed on it. Is it possible to write one method that handles all phones and their cameras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) intent. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image) for more info.